# Why is the question mark like this in Hebrew language?

Tags: hebrew, punctuation, questions, interrogatives

I have tried an interrogative sentence on Google Translate from English to Hebrew and that was "How old are you?"

It translated as what you see in the picture. (of course Hebrew is right to left)

Why is the question mark like what we see in left-to-right languages?

I mean why "?" instead of "؟"

[image]

Comment: Why would you expect "؟"?

Comment: @OmarL All right-to-left languages should have a "؟" as the question mark. "How are you?" and "شما چند ساله هستید؟" are English and Persian respectively. Note that it's the "open side" of the question mark that should face the letters (in both left-to-right and right-to-left languages), not the other side. You can also place a left-to-right interrogative sentence in front of a mirror. The result is a right-to-left sentence with a "؟". Symmetry is important.

Comment: For more information, look at some examples of interrogative sentences in Persian and Arabic.

Comment: There is no such thing as "should have" or "should be" in linguistics, nor in any science.

Comment: I too was surprised by this — Hebrew was my first RTL language and the brain has a hard time not seeing the whole system as a "mirror image". It's not really a mirror image, of course.

Comment: @aminabzz. Symmetry is important - to whom? In what circumstances? To what standard? Why are Arabic final forms not mirror images of Arabic initial forms?

Comment: @ColinFine An RTL language is the mirror image of an LTR language (I'm not saying that the letters should also be mirror images; just the syntax). Arabic initial and final forms are both RTL; so they can't be mirror images of themselves.

Comment: @aminabzz, and I ask what is the basis for your "should". (I could also be pedantic, and point out that LTR and RTL is a property of scripts, not of languages)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is likely to be an unsatisfying answer, but…

### Historical accident. That's just the way it is.

Hebrew imported various punctuation marks from various other languages of Europe fairly early, and kept their forms unchanged (Google points me to [a document from 1784](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5:HaMeassef.JPG)). Other RTL languages (e.g. Arabic) imported them later, and reversed some of them to fit their writing direction.

In linguistics, "this is how the speakers of the language do it" generally matters more than symmetry or aesthetic concerns.

Comment: Or the way I often phrase it: "Language is what it is, not what somebody thinks it should be".

Comment: Thanks. I'm satisfied. BTW, I couldn't post my question on other Hebrew-related sites; that's why I asked it here.